# Pointing towards a specific row jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written a snippet and it is working properly but I want to add another functionality and I don't know how that should be added. Any suggestions would be welcomed. What the snippet is doing is that it traverses through each row and finds a specific cell and does some work on it. What I want to do is get the closest label to each input but I get null. I have removed the complex naming etc to keep the snippet as simple as possible as I want to get the functionality here. Both the input and the label are in the same cell(td). [image: here is the structure of the html cells and row]

```
var count = 0;
$("tr").each(function () {
    var td = $(this).find('td');
    $(td).each(function () {
        var input = $(this).find('input');
        $(input).each(function () {
            count = count +1;
            $(this).closest('label').attr('for', count); //I have alerted this label's text but I got null meaning it isn't getting anything
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I recommend creating a https://jsfiddle.net/ to assist you in this matter. once done add the link to your post

Comment: @Scath I have posted an image of the structure of html

Comment: Closest refers to the closest parent element, you could do `.next()` from input or you can get the parent `td` then `.find()` the label in case there are more complex cell content https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @user3150934 have you read the jQuery API for `.closest()`? And, after realizing `<input>` is **next** to `<label>` what have you googled? Have you tried something like: *`"jQuery get next element"`*? What was the result? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have read the .closest() api and have used it. And if you have read the question I have asked that any suggestions would be really welcomed :)

Comment: May I ask why (instead of using JS) don't you edit your HTML to wrap `<input>` into `<label>` tags? It's allowed and will work out of the box (without a single JS line of code)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I didn't think of that, I am a beginner in Programming. That can also be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing funky stuff with jQuery, edit your HTML and wrap `input` into `label`:

```
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_input_2" value="radio 1">
        radio 1
    </label>
</td>
```

job done. Not a single line of JS.
And no need for `id` and `for` attributes either.